# Is there a way to check if a certain value is appearing week on week using Python?

Tags: python, sql, excel, database, relational-division

I have a dataset with a list of cities and the number of tourists on a week on week basis. I want to do an integrity check of sorts to see if a city is appearing week on week.

The image shows a snapshot of what the dataset looks like, but the actual dataset has close to 1563 cities:

[[image: image[1]]

I want to check if say Harare is appearing consistently throughout the weeks and the same for all other cities (1562 of them).

Comment: Do you want a python solution or an SQL solution is an option?

Comment: @GMB I am working on the project in python but a SQL option can work as well.

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed)

Comment: What do you mean by "is appearing consistently"? Does the city appear in more than half the weeks? Or more than 30 percent of the weeks? Or what?. For example, in this snapshot you attach with 4 weeks and those cities, what will be the output of Harare?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Show what you can do & explain re being stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it is stored in a Panda's Data Frame (named df):

```
no_of_weeks = len(set(df['Week']))
check = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('City').Week.apply(lambda x: x.count() == no_of_weeks))
always_recorded = pd.DataFrame({'City': check.index.values, 'always_recorded': check['Week']})
always_recorded.index = [*range(1, len(always_recorded)+1)]
df2 = pd.merge(df, always_recorded, how = "left", on = "City")
subset = df2[df2.always_recorded == True]
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that each city may appear only once on a given date, one option is to use a relational division technique:

```
select city
from mytable
group by city
having count(*) = (select count(distinct week) from mytable)
```

This gives you all cities that appear for all dates.

If a given city may appear more than once on a given date, then we can sligthly change the `having` clause:

```
having count(distinct week) = (select count(distinct week) from mytable)
```

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution could be to count the number of weeks for each city and match the count to the current week number.

In SQL, you can do something like

```sql
select 
   city, 
   count(week) over (partition by city) as appearance_num
from table_name
```